# How can someone go USA if she is not working and does not have property in india?

Tags: visas, usa

I want to go  USA on Tourist visa. My father wants to sponsor my USA  trip. I do not work and do not have any property and any Tax papers.  What documents i need for visa apply.

Comment: Learn googling and find the information on the official US immigration website.

Answer (score 1):

[US Visas](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/VisaFlyer_B1B2%20March%202015.pdf)

> **Qualifying for a Visitor Visa**
>
> There are specific requirements which must be met by applicants to qualify for a visitor visa under U.S. immigration law. The consular officer at the U.S. Embassy or Consulate will determine whether you qualify for the visa.
>
> **The required presumption under U.S. law is that every visitor visa applicant is an intending immigrant until they demonstrate otherwise. Therefore, applicants for visitor visas must overcome this presumption by demonstrating:**
>
> - That the purpose of their trip is to enter the United States temporarily for business or pleasure;
> - That they plan to remain for a specific, limited period;
> - Evidence of funds to cover expenses in the United States;
> - That they have a residence outside the United States as well as other binding ties that will ensure their departure from the United States at the end of the visit.
>
> **Applying for a Visitor Visa**
>
> Applicants for visitor visas should generally apply at the nearest U.S. Embassy or Consulate in the country where they live. It is important to apply for a visa well in advance of the travel departure date. Completing Form DS-160, Online Nonimmigrant Visa Application, (ceac.state.gov/genniv/), is the first step in the visa application process.
>
> You can learn how to schedule an appointment for an interview, pay the application processing fee, review embassy-specific instructions, and much more by visiting the website of the U.S. Embassy or Consulate where you will be applying at usembassy.gov.